# how to change font size of x-axis & y-axis label of the FusionCharts timeseries chart

Tags: reactjs, fusioncharts, react-fusioncharts

```js
const URL_DATA = 'https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/fusion.store/ft/data/plotting-multiple-series-on-time-axis-data.json';
const URL_SCHEMA = 'https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/fusion.store/ft/schema/plotting-multiple-series-on-time-axis-schema.json';

const jsonify = res => res.json();
const dataFetch = fetch(URL_DATA).then(jsonify);
const schemaFetch = fetch(URL_SCHEMA).then(jsonify);

Promise.all([dataFetch, schemaFetch]).then(([data, schema]) => {
  var fusionTable = new FusionCharts.DataStore().createDataTable(data, schema);

  new FusionCharts({
    type: 'timeseries',
    renderAt: 'container',
    width: "90%",
    height: 490,
    dataSource: {

      caption: {
        text: "Sales Analysis"
      },
      data: fusionTable,
      subcaption: {
        text: "Grocery & Footwear"
      },

      yaxis: [{
        plot: "Sales Value",
        title: "Sale Value",
        format: {
          prefix: "$"
        }
      }],
      categories: [{
        className: 'x-axis-text-class'
      }]
    }
  }).render();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.fusioncharts.com/fusioncharts/latest/fusioncharts.js"></script>
<div id="container">FusionCharts will render here</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVWfK.png)how to change font size of x-axis & y-axis label of the FusionCharts timeseries chart.
https://jsfiddle.net/wgz2ybf1/

I have checked with below way

```
{
  "chart": {
    "yAxisValueFontSize": "10px",
    "yAxisValueFontColor": "#ff0000",
  }
}
```

```
{
  "chart": {
    "baseFont": "Verdana",
    "baseFontSize": "11",
    "baseFontColor": "#0066cc"
  }
}
```